# Javascript web workers: why do I need to postMessage twice to trigger event?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am a newcomer to Javascript and web programming in general.  I am trying to figure out web workers, and have the following code (running in chrome):

worker_example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="worker_example.js"></script>
    </head>
<html>
```

worker_example.js

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    document.write("hello");
}, false);

worker.postMessage("");
```

worker.js

```
// self.postMessage("");
```

My question is why doesn't `worker.postMessage("")` trigger the event?  If I uncomment the single line in worker.js, however, everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event listener attached to `worker` listens for messages coming **from** the worker **to** the parent page. You need to register a listener *in the worker* as well.

parent.js

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  console.log(e.data);
});

worker.postMessage('marco');
```

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data + ' polo');
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  There are two possible directions of communication and so there are two distinct listeners that can be set up.  Thanks!