# Greasemonkey PostMessage mouseup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, greasemonkey

I have a problem, which im trying to solve already some days, but it is not successfully. I have following javascript file, which works fine in included index.html website:

```
    function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
    }
    $(document).ready(function (){
       $('div,pre').mouseup(function (e){
          alert(getSelectionText())})
   });
```

It alerts me selected text on website. (So for simple website works fine). Im using following code in next a little bit more advantage thing.

1. I have index.html, where inside I use iframe (I open website from another domain - for this reason im using greasemonkey, greasemonkey script and postmessages).

My greasemonkey scripts looks:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        localhost iframe script
// @namespace   http://localhost
// @include     http://localhost/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

alert('Test greasemonkey, it works');

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    //alert("test-get-selc");
    return text;
}

$(document).ready(function (){
   $('div,pre').mouseup(function (e){
      // alert(getSelectionText())
      parent.postMessage(getSelectionText(),"*");
   })
}); 

// parent.postMessage("test data","*");
```

And part of my index.html (which is parent of iframe) where I accept postmessage from Iframe:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
                var eventer = window[eventMethod];
                var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

                // Listen to message from child window
                eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
                    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
                    var data = e[key];
                    console.log(data);
                },false);
```

I have also included jquery (hard coded in greasemonkey script). 
So, If I send normal postmessage with "test data" example it works fine and it sends data to receiver. The problem is in .mouseup method, It does not send postmessage with selected text example. Does anyone know how to modify it, that it will work in Greasemonkey script ?
Need to modify next part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('div,pre').mouseup(function (e){
      // alert(getSelectionText())
      parent.postMessage(getSelectionText(),"*");
   })
});
```

And what is the simplest way to debug greasemonkey scripts?

Comment: I believe you need to use `unsafeWindow` instead of `window` when writing greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: Are you sure is that reason?:o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript web workers: why do I need to postMessage twice to trigger event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328826/javascript-web-workers-why-do-i-need-to-postmessage-twice-to-trigger-event)